# browser-nginx compression priority

Tags: nginx, gzip

Nginx with enabled both brotli and gzip compressions replies:

```
curl -s -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: br,gzip,deflate' https://something
content-encoding: gzip
curl -s -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: br'  https://something
content-encoding: br
```

any chance to set a kind of priority in browser/nginx?
Why and how Nginx decide to reply "gzip" when several options supported?